# how to avoid url address manipulation

Tags: php, laravel, url

in ***laravel*** how do i stop my ***url*** address from showing data ***everytime*** i changed the id example below.

**Example:**
http://localhost:8000/posts/**11** --***DEFAULT***

If they change the **id** like the example below it will return to the ***DEFAULT*** or go to forbidden page.
http://localhost:8000/posts/**12**

http://localhost:8000/posts/**13**

http://localhost:8000/posts/**14**

Comment: if 12 is not present then it will goes to 404 or forbidden itself. if exist then you can't control this behaviour

Comment: Is it because some of this post are protected for some user? If yes, use firewall maybe to protect your page, if the user has no right to see the post you display an error message or redirect him

Comment: If you get 11 and get data from DB is workes fine then if DB has 12 then its also works fine. It means you cant do it

Comment: yes, its present, is there anyway i could hide the id?

Comment: i want to protect my data from being viewed if id will show

Comment: don't use `id` in url

Comment: do you have any idea that could help this matter..

Comment: I don't really know Laravel but I work a little with PHP framework (Symfony, Silex), you can maybe use some Ajax to load your posts content after a click and keep only your URL `/posts/content` or soemthing like that maybe, or use Firewall to check user right to see some post and not other

Comment: how to do it? not using id

Comment: try reading about middlewares in Laravel.

Comment: is this about routing?

Comment: @Copain I think you are in a page `/posts` and when user click on one posts you send him to `/posts/id` no? Try to do the same but you send him to `/posts/content` and send the id in $_POST or I don't know to still display the good content, maybe?

Comment: @ Mickael Leger yeah you are right, how to changed it into content?

Comment: Use a slug for your post's url (`str_slug()`), harder to guess/swap than an int.